# How to populate a list of objects that contain arrays in them?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, class

So for starters here's the class I've made:

```
public class Module
{
    public string name = "";
    public string modDesc = "";
    public string[] chdesc = new string[8];
    public string[] tag = new string[8];
    public string[] address = new string[8];
}
```

Now, I'm trying to make a list of these modules like so:

`List<Module> moduleList = new List<Module>();`

and when it comes to populating this list I would like to do something like this:

`moduleList.Add(new Module { name = "1734-IB4D", modDesc = "4-CH Diagnostic Input Module", address[0] = "this doesnt work"});`

but the last property there of `address[0] = "this doesnt work"` throws an error. How do I initialize a new Module object and add it to my list then? Would I have to build the array ahead of time and then add it in the example above? What do you recommend?

Comment: is this c# or java?

Comment: Good question @DanielA.White, I was also wondering :)

Comment: @Capn, add the language in the tag sections to ease things for those helping you please.

Comment: If `new List<Module>()` compiles, I'm guessing it's C#.

Comment: @DanielA.White frick sorry guys it's c# I just edited it now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing array elements of a List<object\[\]> in foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400945/accessing-array-elements-of-a-listobject-in-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer to my own question. Instead of setting each entry to the variable in the add section I'd set the array value equal to another array. So what I ended up with was:

`string[] someArray = { "1", "2", "3' };
moduleList.Add(new Module { name = "1734-IR2", modDesc = "2-CH RTD Input Module", address = someArray });`

and that seems to work fine. If anyone knows how to properly do what I was trying above then please post it here too. Nice to have options.

Comment: You can't do what you want in an initializer.  You have to set it after initializing the class.

Comment: @DStanley - You should be able to do this all in one line though:  `moduleList.Add(new Module { name = "1734-IR2", modDesc = "2-CH RTD Input Module", address = new[] { "1", "2", "3" } });`

Comment: @Icemanind True, but that's assigning a _new_ array to the property.  OP wants to keep the array that was creates in the field initializer and set item 0 to a specific value.

Comment: @Icemanind yeah that works too! Thanks thats the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Module> moduleList = new List<Module>();

Module _module = new Module();
_module.name = "1734-IB4D";
_module.modDesc = "4-CH Diagnostic Input Module";
_module.address[0] = "this doesnt work"

moduleList.Add(_module);
```

Comment: This doesn't help me because I need to add a lot of these modules and I don't know how many I'll need hence the use of a list in the first place. Thanks for the reply though!